# WebView extract and edit html

Tags: android, html, http, replace, webview

I am creating a very simple WebView application on android. However, I want to edit the html file before displaying it in the WebView.

For example, if the original html source looked like :

```
<html>   
  <body>
    <h1> abc </h1>
    <h2> abc </h2>
    ......
    <h6> abc </h6>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I want to change it to:

```
<html>   
  <body>
    <h1> cba </h1>
    <h2> cba </h2>
    ......
    <h6> cba </h6>
  </body>
</html>
```

(all "abc" become "cba")
And then, I want to display that new code in my WebView. How can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why do you need this and what kind of app it is to need this. But if you have to do it check foll code:

```
$(function() {
    for(var i =0;i<101;i++) {
        if(jQuery('h'+i).length)
            jQuery('h'+i).html(jQuery('h'+i).html().split("").reverse().join(""));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a note on your header tags: `<h100>` is a common misconception for newcomers. `<h_>` tags are simply an organizational item for your page, and only go out to `<h6>` You can have multiple `<h1>` tags on the same page, which are just headings for that section of content (with `<h2>` implying a subsection of `<h1>`, etc).

From there, when you say "original source", I assume you mean this is your own code, correct? Not a WebView sourced from another site? If this is the case, and you are only looking to change a specific instance of a specific string in your own code, a Find and Replace should be sufficient via any text or code editor you are using.

But if this is the case, you might want to look into first learning HTML and being able to render it in a basic web browser before moving on to also trying to learn Android.

Comment: The html code is merely an example, not real code. I wanted to give an example of how I wanted to replace several parts of the code instead of just a few. Thanks for the tip though...
Sorry for not clarifying before, but this is not my own source. It is a WebView of site that is not owned by me.